# Power Query Find First and Last non blank cell in each column and reference the startdate column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I've created a formula in excel that finds the first and last non blank cell and returns the corresponding date found in the startdate column.  I need to repeat this on a large database (csv file of more than 1Gb in size of which there are about 200K rows with 1216 columns) and so rather than loading it up in excel I would like to use Power Query to do the hard work and return a simple table which details the QID headers (in one column) and the oldest and newest date for where a value is found, for each column (QID).  Doing it in PowerQuery will then mean I can easily point to different source files and not have to load up the whole file into excel in the first place which is extremely slow not forgetting the formula itself!

Below is a picture of my efforts in excel with the formula for cell E19 as :

```
=TEXT(index($D$4:$D$17,MIN(IF(len(E$4:E$17)>0,row($D$4:$D$17)-3,""))),"dd/mm/yyyy")&" to "&TEXT(index($D$4:$D$17,Max(IF(len(E$4:E$17)>0,row($D$4:$D$17)-3,""))),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I have imported the table into Power query and thought my first step would be to get the headers only and transpose them into a new query / table but then I'm not sure how I can create two new columns one for lowest and highest date and reference each column in the original table (let's call it DataTable) based on each QID name or column number.  I also will need to run a find and replace as blank cells need to be replaced with null so that it finds the true first and last entry (that could be done in notepad++ if that would be a more efficient way).

Please could someone provide some guidance in the steps I need to do?

Thanks

Rodp

[image]

=========================
update 13/3/24

Thanks to Ron and Kevin for the advice so far.  Both examples get me a little closer but they are not picking up the first on blank cell.  It seems to be picking up the first cell outright.

I'd like to provide an example of the data here but pasting it here may not copy over the data as it's seen in excel (we're talking about empty cells vs blank cells) but here goes anyway.  I've converted it to csv.

Here's a smallscreen shot to help
[image]

```
startDate,Attribute,Value
10/07/2022 06:19,QID270,
10/07/2022 08:06,QID270,
11/07/2022 11:57,QID270,
11/07/2022 11:59,QID270,
11/07/2022 12:08,QID270,
11/07/2022 12:18,QID270,Yes
11/07/2022 13:11,QID270,
11/07/2022 22:20,QID270,No
11/07/2022 22:34,QID270,
12/12/2022 10:15,QID270,
12/12/2022 10:16,QID270,
12/12/2022 10:16,QID270,No
12/12/2022 10:16,QID270,
13/12/2022 22:46,QID270,
13/12/2022 22:54,QID270,
13/12/2022 23:49,QID270,
13/12/2022 23:52,QID270,
```

The first nonblank cell should reuslt in a date: 11/07/2022 12:18 but at the moment powerquery returns 10/07/2022 06:19.  Likewise the last entry should be 12/12/2022 but it's retuning 13/12/2022

I've tried two methods.  I've made sure the empty cells in powerquery have null in them.

List First (returns 10/07/2022 06:19:04)

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Attribute"}, {"Min Date", each List.First(List.RemoveNulls(List.RemoveFirstN(Source[startDate],0))), type nullable datetime})
```

List Min (returns 10/07/2022 to 13/12/2022)

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Attribute"}, {
    {"First/Last", (t)=> Date.ToText(List.Min(t[startDate]),"dd/MM/yyyy"" to """) & Date.ToText(List.Max(t[startDate]), "dd/MM/yyyy")
    }})
```

Thanks in advance
Rodp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to show what you show for your output in your screenshot:

- Transpose the data
- Add a column in which we calculate the first and last dates

  - Remove all the nulls each row.
  - Find the position of the first and last (non-null) entry
  - Return the corresponding Date from the first row (which has all the dates from the original table)
  - Create a formatted string as you show in your screenshot
- Delete the first row and also all the columns except the first and last.

*The algorithm assumes that dates are in descending order as you show*

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],

//set datetime column to propert type
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{"StartDate", type datetime}),

//Demote headers and Transpose
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),

//Add a column showing the first and last dates
//output results as a string
    #"Add First/Last" = Table.AddColumn(#"Transposed Table", "First/Last", (r)=>
        let 
            li = List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList(r),1),
            first = List.RemoveNulls(li){0},
            last = List.RemoveNulls(List.Reverse(li)){0},
            #"Last Date" = Date.From(Record.ToList(#"Transposed Table"{0}) {List.PositionOf(li,first,Occurrence.First)+1}),
            #"First Date" = Date.From(Record.ToList(#"Transposed Table"{0}){List.PositionOf(li,last,Occurrence.Last)+1})
        in 
            Date.ToText(#"First Date","dd/MM/yyyy"" to """) & Date.ToText(#"Last Date", "dd/MM/yyyy"), type text),

//Remove all except first and last columns
//Remove first row
    result = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.RemoveFirstN(#"Add First/Last",1), List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Add First/Last"),1),1))
in

    result
```

[image]

***Edit:***    Since you wrote the above was slow on your dataset, try the following where we use Unpivot and Table.Group to come up with the same result:

***Edit2:** Ensure blanks are ignored*

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],

//set datetime column to date
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{"StartDate", type date}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"StartDate"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {
        {"First/Last", (x)=> let t=Table.SelectRows(x, each [Value]<>null) 
            in 
                Date.ToText(List.Min(t[StartDate]),"dd/MM/yyyy"" to """) & 
                Date.ToText(List.Max(t[StartDate]), "dd/MM/yyyy"), type text
        }}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks very much @RonRosenfield for the guidance and code.  I did try transposing but it was taking a very long time to read the data so I thought there must be a better way and by each field as a column rather than a row.  But if transposing is the only way, I will give it a go.  Will come back with an update shortly! :)

Comment: @Rodp See my edit where I use Unpivot and Table.Group. Perhaps it will execute more quickly.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that and come back :)

Comment: thanks @RonRsenfield, have used this version as on 27 columns during my test it took 1min 4s compared to use the UI group by method with took 1min 24s.  So over 1000 columns this wlll be quicker.  Not sure why.  Thanks. again.

Comment: @Rodp Thx. BTW, in Power Bi desktop there is a diagnostic tool which can show the timing for each step in the process. I sometimes find it useful to figure out why one method might be faster than another.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfield.  Sorry but is commenting here the right way to update you?  I can't post images here can I?  There is a problem in that It's not recognising where the first non-blank cell is occurring so it's just reporting the first and last date in the list.  A google suggested using List.First combined with List.RemoveNulls but still no luck.  I also tried replacing blank with null.

eg. = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {"Min Date", each List.First(List.RemoveNulls(List.RemoveFirstN(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[startDate],0))), type nullable datetime})

Comment: @Rodp The output is the same as you show in your example. You'll have to provide an example that shows the problem. You can edit your question but please show your example as **text**, not a picture.

Comment: @RonRosenfield, i've added some more detail and data as text.  If I could suggest you copy and paste it into a table in excel then get it into powerquery making sure the empty cells are nulls then that should be the same as to what I have at this end.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rodp Thank you. See edit 2 in my answer. the rows with blank `Values` are being removed from each subgroup before processing.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfield, thanks for the revised code - I would never have figured that out.  I tried scaling edit 2 up but it's very slow (5-15MB per minute).  I went back to the previous edit (edit 1) but removed the nulls in a prior stuep and that sped it up (100MB per 20 sec) with the dates looking correct.  The only caveat is that I won't know which QID's are totally blank (but I could use a master list in excel to get round that).  So thanks very much indeed for all your advice.  I'll mark this as the answer - (Edit 1 + remove nulls beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using unpivot and group, instead of transpose.

Unpivot the QID columns to a single column, and remove the rows with blank QID values

[image]

Group by QID, with a Min date and Max date

[image]

Extract date and merge

[image]

Comment: thanks @kevin I will give that a go which I think Ron was suggesting in his comments but thanks for the screenshots, that will help alot.

Comment: thanks @kevin , have tested and works ok.  I tested it on 27 columns but discovered that the UI group by method (ie creating a separate column for min and max date)  was about 20 seconds longer (1min 24s instead of 1min 4s).  As I've got about 1000 columns, I will choose the combined min and max time but it's interesting to discover the difference in time it takes.  Thanks again.